# How to draw Triangle star pattern with MySQL without using Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

[Triangular pattern example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TJ7H.png) The above pattern is for p(5). How to write a query to print the pattern P(n) (where n is Integer defining the number of rows) using **MySQL** without using **Stored Procedure**. I had one code example for **MS SQL Server** i.e.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 20
WHILE (@i > 0) 
BEGIN
   PRINT REPLICATE('* ', @i) 
   SET @i = @i - 1
END
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SET @NUMBER = 21;
SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1)
    FROM information_schema.tables LIMIT 20;
```

OR

```
SET @NUMBER = 21;
SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1)
    FROM information_schema.tables WHERE @NUMBER > 1;
```

Comment: Can you please explain this, like how is it able to switch and print in a new-line?

Comment: @swingcake
Sorry, I don't know how I missed that.

if one removed `from information_schema.tables` it will print as string, as sql processed it as single line. however, once there is `from` it will iterate on each row in table until it fulfills the conditions or the table, in our case 20 times based on our `where` condition.

if this table includes more than 20 rows and queried without `where` it will keep printing until the rows are finished.

and one can choose whatever table.

you can fiddle here if you like with table players

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s2WG4tdymxkEb1AWXiSPii/0

Comment: Thank you. This works, however I don't know why we are referencing information_schema.tables?? What is this referring to?

Comment: @JackSparrow123 yw! [information_schema is a schema with a set of standard views/tables depending on specific database engine providing access to the database metadata and data dictionary](https://dataedo.com/kb/databases/all/information_schema) .....
referencing Wikipedia 1st cite note [In relational databases, the information schema 'information_schema' is an ANSI-standard set of read-only views that provide information about all of the tables, views, columns, and procedures in a database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema#cite_note-1)

Comment: as for why using it.. any table can be used as long as its rows are more than the required repetition. also, information_schema is guaranteed to be there, so it is more handy in an random example.

Answer (score 2):

The below query to print the pattern P(20).

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS n, CAST('*' AS CHAR(100)) AS str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1, concat('* ',str) FROM cte WHERE n < 20
)
SELECT str FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @NUMBER = 21;
SELECT REPEAT('* ', @NUMBER := @NUMBER - 1)
    FROM information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: But what if value of n is more than number of rows in information.schema.

Answer (score 1):

also for this pattern:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
...
```

the query:

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT REPEAT('* ', @i := @i + 1)
    FROM information_schema.tables
    where @i < 20; --p(20)
```